# Using JMeter for functional testing (No Load) - a single response is causing the UI to hang

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to promote JMeter functional testing as it provides so many tools to debug the API responses, but if it hangs even for a single response, it is not liked and people are not adopting it.

I am not doing performance testing, only functional testing of a single API. I am using JMeter because it provides very handy extractors for extracting JSON and XML objects.

I am observing even for a single request the UI is hanging. I don't want to run in CLI mode as my requirement is with UI and the listeners in which I can see the XML & JSON responses.

Yes the response is huge amount of data but it works in Post-Man.

Is there any way I can stop that hanging by increasing the heap memory etc.

Comment: Take a thread dump of the JVM and see where it is hanging.

Comment: It is hanging in listener "View Result Tree" when I click on the sample. Also when I try to change the format of response like xpath/Json etc...it hangs

Answer (score 0):

As per [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter of JMeter Best Practices:

> Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.

If the response is huge it might be the case it doesn't fit into memory so in order to troubleshoot the issue you can:

1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
2. Take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see what threads are in blocked/waiting state

You might need to increase the [JVM Heap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap) size allocated to JMeter as default setting of 1 GB might not be enough for displaying large responses, see [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more details.

Comment: There is a single thread, single request. The problem I am facing is after execution when I am verifying some fields in the response with the xpath view of "VIEW RESULTS TREE"

Comment: If the response is "huge" it might be the case it doesn't fit fully into the View Results Tree listener, by default it shows first 10 MB of data only, if this is your case you can add the next line to *user.properties* file: `view.results.tree.max_size=0`. JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and  [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) articles for more details.